# try catch coding pattern in python

Tags: python

I'm dealing with a set of 3rd party python scripts.  I'm noticing this general pattern of enumerating many different Exception classes with no different action taken but logging a string representation of the exception that would be caught.

```
except AttributeError as ae:
        print("Attribute Error while processing the configuration file!\n{0}\n".format( str(ae) ) )
        intReturnValue = 1
    except IndexError as ie:
        print("Index Error while processing the configuration file!\n{0}\n".format( str(ie) ) )
        intReturnValue = 1
    except NameError as ne:
        print("Name Error while processing the configuration file!\n{0}\n".format( str(ne) ) )
        intReturnValue = 1
    except TypeError as te:
        print("Type Error while processing the configuration file!\n{0}\n".format( str(te) ) )
        intReturnValue = 1
    except:
        print("Unexpected error while processing the configuration file!\n{0}\n".format( sys.exc_info()[0] ) )
        intReturnValue = 1
```

Is this pattern some kind of pythonism or more just the author?  It seems python allows you to have a general case catch block.  Wouldn't it be simpler in this case to just use that and generate the log message a bit more dynamically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow, that is pretty poor code. You certainly can catch a series of exceptions at once and log them:

```
except (AttributeError, IndexError, NameError, TypeError) as e:
    print "%s was raised... " % (e.__class__.__name__)
```

Of course, you should then probably determine why that code needs to catch all those different exception types. It sounds like something seriously wrong with the processing code itself.

Comment: I was going to say that, but I had to look it up! Too fast, man.

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to write this would be

```
except (AttributeError, IndexError, NameError, TypeError) as ex:
    print("{} while processing the configuration file!\n{}\n".format(type(ex).__name, ex)
except BaseException:
        print("Unexpected error while processing the configuration file!\n{0}\n".format( sys.exc_info()[0] ) )
```

Or better yet:

```
except BaseException as ex:
    print("{} while processing the configuration file!\n{}\n".format(type(ex).__name, ex)
```

**EDIT**

Catching BaseException is generally bad, but no worse than a bare `except`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to do something like

```
ERROR_CONDITIONS = AttributeError,IndexError,NameError,TypeError
try:
   ...
except ERROR_CONDITIONS as ae:
    print("Attribute Error while processing the configuration file!\n{0}\n".format( str(ae) ) )
    intReturnValue = 1
except:
     #unknown errror
```